# Using background jobs to upload files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Uploading files on my server would take a lot of time,is it possible to upload a file and allow a background process to take over the upload after validations so that it does not slowdown the application and how can i go about this.

my file controller is like this

```
@file = File.new(params[:file])
      respond_to do |format|
      if @file.save
        format.html { redirect_to @file, notice: 'file was successfully uploaded.' }
        format.json { render json: @file, status: :created, location: @file }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @file.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
end
```

the file model is like this

```
 has_attached_file :file,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:normalized_file_file_name",
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:normalized_file_file_name"
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => ['audio/mp3', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/mid', 'audio/x-wav']

  Paperclip.interpolates :normalized_file_file_name do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.normalized_file_file_name
  end

  def normalized_mp3_file_name
    "#{self.mp3_file_name.gsub( /[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]/, ' ')}"
  end
```

where would i use the delayed job gem and how

Comment: Can you deploy your app as threaded or it's only shared-nothing ?

Comment: @clyfe i just updated the question for a quick glance

Comment: delayed_job may be used to background the file processing (if any) but I belive it cannot background the uploading, because upload requires an open connection with the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your files are large in size it will definitely take a lot of time to upload. And background processing at client side can not happen because you need some solution which could upload file without taking much time or carry late response. An answer to this problem could help you here is using jquery to upload your files and you can have validation at client end using jquery too(which is not a good thing but, yes it will fulfil the purpose).

I have used this - http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ for my project. But there are more available to suit your desire. Check them if you'd like to here - http://creativefan.com/10-ajax-jquery-file-uploaders/

I hope it helps you to solve this issue.